# How can I improve the performance of my postgresql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, optimization, query-optimization

I have a query which returns a sum of buys, sells and transfers over an interval grouped by account, the problem is it is quite slow and I am only doing it for transactions in the last 24 hours, I would like to be able to run this for all transactions ever (800,000 over 2 years). How can I optimise this?

```
select
    i.interval, ca.contract_address,
    coalesce(SUM(t.amount) FILTER (WHERE t.action = 0), 0) as amount_ampl_bought,
    coalesce(SUM(t.amount) FILTER (WHERE t.action = 1), 0) as amount_ampl_sold,
    coalesce(SUM(t.amount) FILTER (WHERE t.action = 2), 0) as amount_ampl_transferred,
    coalesce(SUM(t.supply_percentage) FILTER (WHERE t.action = 0), 0) as percent_ampl_bought,
    coalesce(SUM(t.supply_percentage) FILTER (WHERE t.action = 1), 0) as percent_ampl_sold,
    coalesce(SUM(t.supply_percentage) FILTER (WHERE t.action = 2), 0) as percent_ampl_transferred
from
    (
        select contract_address
        from addresses a
        where not exists (select 1 from address_tags at where at.address = a.contract_address and at.tag_id = 3)
    ) ca
cross join
    (
        SELECT date_trunc('hour', dd) as interval
        FROM generate_series
        (
            (now() at time zone 'utc') - interval '1 day',
            (now() at time zone 'utc'),
            '1 hour'::interval
        ) dd
    ) i
left join transfers t on (t.from = ca.contract_address or t.to = ca.contract_address) and date_trunc('hour', t.timestamp at time zone 'utc') = i.interval
group by i.interval, ca.contract_address;
```

Example output:

```
      interval       |              contract_address              | amount_ampl_bought | amount_ampl_sold | amount_ampl_transferred |     percent_ampl_bought     |     percent_ampl_sold      |  percent_ampl_transferred  
---------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
 2021-05-08 11:00:00 | 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 |                  0 |                0 |                       0 |                           0 |                          0 |                          0
 2021-05-08 11:00:00 | 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead |                  0 |                0 |                       0 |                           0 |                          0 |                          0
 2021-05-08 11:00:00 | 0x000000000000006f6502b7f2bbac8c30a3f67e9a |                  0 |                0 |                       0 |                           0 |                          0 |                          0
 2021-05-08 11:00:00 | 0x000000000000084e91743124a982076c59f10084 |                  0 |                0 |                       0 |                           0 |                          0 |                          0
 2021-05-08 11:00:00 | 0x0000000000000eb4ec62758aae93400b3e5f7f18 |                  0 |                0 |                       0 |                           0 |                          0 |                          0
 2021-05-08 11:00:00 | 0x00000000000017c75025d397b91d284bbe8fc7f2 |                  0 |                0 |                       0 |                           0 |                          0 |                          0
 2021-05-08 11:00:00 | 0x0000000000005117dd3a72e64a705198753fdd54 |                  0 |                0 |                       0 |                           0 |                          0 |                          0
 2021-05-08 11:00:00 | 0x000000000000740a22fa209cf6806d38f7605385 |                  0 |                0 |                       0 |                           0 |                          0 |                          0
```

Link to query visualised:

https://explain.depesz.com/s/SrLf

Indexes I have created on transfers:

```
 CREATE INDEX transfers_from_to_index ON public.transfers USING btree ("from", "to")
 CREATE INDEX transfers_timestamp_index ON public.transfers USING btree ("timestamp")
 CREATE INDEX transfers_action_index ON public.transfers USING btree (action)
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX transfers_pkey ON public.transfers USING btree (transaction_hash, log_index)
 CREATE INDEX transfers_supply_percentage_index ON public.transfers USING btree (supply_percentage)
 CREATE INDEX transfers_amount_index ON public.transfers USING btree (amount)
 CREATE INDEX transfers_supply_percentage_timestamp_log_index_index ON public.transfers USING btree (supply_percentage, "timestamp", log_index)
 CREATE INDEX transfers_date_trunc_idx ON public.transfers USING btree (date_trunc('hour'::text, timezone('utc'::text, "timestamp")))
 CREATE INDEX transfers_to_index ON public.transfers USING btree ("to")
```

Indexes I have created on addresses:

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX addresses_pkey ON public.addresses USING btree (contract_address)
 CREATE INDEX addresses_supply_percentage_index ON public.addresses USING btree (supply_percentage)
```

Many thanks for your help with this optimisation!

Comment: It would help if you qualified *all* column references so it is clear where the columns are coming from.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I'll do that now!

Comment: How long does it take if you remove the LEFT from join?  Maybe it would be faster to get just the data which exists, and fill in the missing values via a different mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the problem is the `or` in the `JOIN` condition on `transfers`.  Under reasonable assumptions you should be able to split this into two separate `left join`s:

```
select i.interval, a.contract_address,
       coalesce(SUM(tt.amount, tf.amount) FILTER (WHERE COALESCE(tt.action, tf.acount) = 0), 0) as amount_ampl_bought,
       coalesce(SUM(tt.amount, tf.amount) FILTER (WHERE COALESCE(tt.action, tf.acount) = 1), 0) as amount_ampl_sold,
       coalesce(SUM(tt.amount, tf.amount) FILTER (WHERE COALESCE(tt.action, tf.acount) = 2), 0) as amount_ampl_transferred,
       coalesce(SUM(tt.supply_percentage, tf.supply_percentage) FILTER (WHERE COALESCE(tt.action, tf.acount) = 0), 0) as percent_ampl_bought,
       coalesce(SUM(tt.supply_percentage, tf.supply_percentage) FILTER (WHERE COALESCE(tt.action, tf.acount) = 1), 0) as percent_ampl_sold,
       coalesce(SUM(tt.supply_percentage, tf.supply_percentage) FILTER (WHERE COALESCE(tt.action, tf.acount) = 2), 0) as percent_ampl_transferred
from addresses a cross join
     generate_series(date_trunc('hour', (now() at time zone 'utc') - interval '1 hour'),
                     date_trunc('hour', now() at time zone 'utc'),
                     '1 hour'::interval
                    ) i left join
      transfers tf
      on tf.from = ca.contract_address and
         date_trunc('hour', tf.timestamp at time zone 'utc') = i.interval left join
      transfers tt
      on t.to = ca.contract_address and
         date_trunc('hour', tt.timestamp at time zone 'utc') = i.interval
where not exists (select 1
                  from address_tags at
                  where at.address = a.contract_address and at.tag_id = 3
                 )
group by i.interval, ca.contract_address;
```

Then for this query, you want indexes on:

- `address_tags(address, tag_id)`
- `transfers(to, timestamp)`
- `transfers(from, timestamp)`

(Note that `to` and `from` are really bad names for columns because they are SQL keywords.)

The conversion of `timetamp` to UTC could also pose a problem.  I would suggest that you fix your data so that timestamps are all in a common timezone -- and I would suggest UTC for that purpose (to avoid issues with daylight saving time).

Comment: All my timestamps are in UTC format already, but to create an index on date_trunc postgres complained about it needing to not be immutable so I specified the timezone UTC there and then subsequently in the query just to be sure? But the data is all stored in UTC format.

I realised after initial creation that to and from were keywords, my apologies for that. I'll test this and report back, many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is already doing most of the work for all time periods, just filtering out the ones you didn't ask for after most of the work was done.  So if you want a different time period, just do it.  If that is still too slow, then post the plan for that.  Then at least we would be optimizing the right query.

Comment: All I do in the other query is increase the amount I take off the interval e.g. for all time in generate series I would do now minus a year. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Without seeing the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS), or at least the EXPLAIN, I wouldn't know.

Comment: Here it is for a year (all time would be about 3 years):

https://explain.depesz.com/s/M3Ur

Answer (score 0):

Could you give below a try? AFAIK there is no reason to cram everything in 1 query so I split some of the parts of.
I also split the `or` into 2 parts, it should allow for better usage of the indexes. And then noticed that's exactly what Gordon already did above (so far for me thinking was so clever for finding a workaround that's probably faster than UNION ALL =)

Also added WHERE on action, not sure if there are other values than 0, 1, 2. If not you can remove that again.

PS: untested and working blind here, simply being curious (and hopeful =)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _combined;

WITH intervals
  AS ( 
       SELECT i as interval            
          FROM generate_series(
                                date_trunc('hour', (now() at time zone 'utc') - interval '1 day'),
                                date_trunc('hour', (now() at time zone 'utc')),
                                '1 hour'::interval
                            ) ,
     adrs 
  AS (
        SELECT a.contract_address
          FROM addresses a 
        EXCEPT
        SELECT at.address 
          FROM address_tags at
         WHERE at.tag_id = 3)
         
SELECT a.contract_address, i.interval
  INTO TEMPORARY TABLE _combined
  FROM intervals i
 CROSS JOIN adrs a
           
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq_combined ON _combined (interval, contract_address)

SELECT c.interval, 
       c.contract_address,
       COALESCE(SUM(COALESCE(tf.amount           , tt.amount           , 0)) FILTER (WHERE t.action = 0), 0) as amount_ampl_bought,
       COALESCE(SUM(COALESCE(tf.amount           , tt.amount           , 0)) FILTER (WHERE t.action = 1), 0) as amount_ampl_sold,
       COALESCE(SUM(COALESCE(tf.amount           , tt.amount           , 0)) FILTER (WHERE t.action = 2), 0) as amount_ampl_transferred,
       COALESCE(SUM(COALESCE(tf.supply_percentage, tt.supply_percentage, 0)) FILTER (WHERE t.action = 0), 0) as percent_ampl_bought,
       COALESCE(SUM(COALESCE(tf.supply_percentage, tt.supply_percentage, 0)) FILTER (WHERE t.action = 1), 0) as percent_ampl_sold,
       COALESCE(SUM(COALESCE(tf.supply_percentage, tt.supply_percentage, 0)) FILTER (WHERE t.action = 2), 0) as percent_ampl_transferred
  FROM _combined c

  LEFT OUTER JOIN transfers tf 
               ON tf.from = c.contract_address  
              AND date_trunc('hour', tf.timestamp at time zone 'utc') = c.interval
              AND tf.action IN (0, 1, 2)

  LEFT OUTER JOIN transfers tt 
               ON tt.to = c.contract_address 
              AND date_trunc('hour', tt.timestamp at time zone 'utc') = c.interval
              AND tt.action IN (0, 1, 2)
       
group by c.interval, c.contract_address;
```

ideal indexes for this query would be:

```
CREATE INDEX transfers_date_trunc_to_idx ON public.transfers USING btree (date_trunc('hour'::text, timezone('utc'::text, "timestamp"), to)) INCLUDE (action, amount, supply_percentage) 
CREATE INDEX transfers_date_trunc_from_idx ON public.transfers USING btree (date_trunc('hour'::text, timezone('utc'::text, "timestamp"), from)) INCLUDE (action, amount, supply_percentage)
```

Comment: I will give this a try this evening, thanks for getting back to me!